# How to stop configuration component class bean functions to get executed during mvn clean install?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

In the configuration component class, I have a bean function where I have a listener which runs in an infinite loop that continuously reads the Redis list. Now while building the application using `mvn clean install` command, it runs this code and goes into an infinite loop. I just want to run this code during running the jar `java -jar test.jar` and not during `mvn clean install` step.
Is there any way or workaround during the build step I can skip this code from execution? Is there any `mvn` command to achieve this?

Comment: The code of your jar is not run during the build. Unless, of course, it is test code.

Comment: @JFabianMeier
The class is defined with `@Component` and also method is defined as `@Bean` annotations. When I do mvn clean install, it runs this code and even during running jar this code gets executed.

Comment: You probably need to show us your POM. Did you define an `exec` plugin execution or something like that. Maven normally never runs the code, it just builds it.

Comment: @JFabianMeier
`<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>`
Above build block is mentioned in pom and some other dependencies.